# Ganymed SSH for java connect issue

Tags: java, ssh

We are using the Ganymed-SSH library and facing this error while doing SSH to another machine.

```
[root@XXXX test]# java -classpath .:ganymed-ssh2-build210.jar Basic 

ERROR:java.io.IOException: There was a problem while connecting to 10.X.X.X:22
java.io.IOException: There was a problem while connecting to 10.X.X.X:22
    at ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:699)
    at ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:490)
    at Basic.main(Basic.java:27)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Key exchange was not finished, connection is closed.
    at ch.ethz.ssh2.transport.KexManager.getOrWaitForConnectionInfo(KexManager.java:91)
    at   ch.ethz.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.getConnectionInfo(TransportManager.java:229)
    at ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:655)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot read full block, EOF reached.
    at ch.ethz.ssh2.crypto.cipher.CipherInputStream.getBlock(CipherInputStream.java:81)
    at ch.ethz.ssh2.crypto.cipher.CipherInputStream.read(CipherInputStream.java:108)
    at ch.ethz.ssh2.transport.TransportConnection.receiveMessage(TransportConnection.java:231)
    at ch.ethz.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.receiveLoop(TransportManager.java:669)
    at ch.ethz.ssh2.transport.TransportManager$1.run(TransportManager.java:468)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

Can anyone explain what could be the issue here? Where should we start to debug from?
SSH access from normal shell works correctly.

Comment: What does the server log say? You could try upping the debug level on the server to get more info.

Comment: :( i dont have permissions to restart the target sshd in debug mode

Comment: You could also try `strace` on the *sshd* daemon thread (although you might have have permission to do that either...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ssh failed after 141742-01/02 patch on solaris 10 !

Enabled aes192/aes256 support in ssh/sshd does not work on S10u3 or older released

A workaround is to disable the use of aes192/aes256 ciphers for ssh and sshd. Change the two config files /etc/ssh/ssh_config and /etc/ssh/sshd_config and add the following line:

Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,arcfour,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc

You’ll have to restart sshd to pickup the change (“svcadm restart ssh”).

Source:
http://blog.mydream.com.hk/howto/matching-cipher-is-not-supported-aes256-cbc

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is some problem with your public key

Comment: public key of the target machine or the source?